# Dynamodb update based on other field

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Currently I have a **posts** table which stores **likes** and **popularity**, basically I want to change the **popularity** field depending on this **likes** field, such as:

```
if (likes > 100) popularity = 3
else if (likes > 50) popularity = 2
else if (likes > 10) popularity = 1
else popularity = 0
```

Popularity(0) means the post is new, whereas popularity(3) posts are the ones users see the most on their explore page.

Right now I need to fetch each post to get their total **likes** and then call an update for its **popularity**. Is there a way to do this in one single update function without fetching the post beforehand?

Comment: How are you updating `likes`? Do you know its value at the time you update its value or are you simply issuing a fire-and-forget increment/decrement?

Comment: @jarmod Currently each time a user clicks like/dislike (1 or -1), it will update a key-value pair using redis (post PK as key, and { likes, dislikes } as value). Every 10 minutes, I will empty this redis "queue", in which likes and popularity will be updated for all the posts inside this queue. So basically I only do fire-and-forget mechanism atm :)

Comment: I'd be tempted to enumerate the unique post IDs from the batch you read from the like/dislike queue, batch retrieve those posts, then aggregate the likes/dislikes per post ID, and finally submit a batch update of all posts to include the new count of likes and the updated popularity. Assuming that you won't have concurrent processes doing this task.

Comment: Another option might be DynamoDB Streams where you filter updates to posts and then update the popularity based on the indicated likes value. That's a delayed mechanism to create a calculated field, I suppose. Not aware of a way to do this as a direct consequence of updating the `likes` value in a single update.

Comment: Why not simply get_item before the update for the likes count and update the popularity score with this logic from the client side?

Comment: @Guy would it be not safe since user can just fake the likes? Also I am doing batch update using a queue system on Redis 

Comment: @jezz, the client-side is your backend server that captures the likes, the users can't fake the popularity without faking the likes, which can do anyway if I understand your architecture correctly.

Comment: @Guy Oh I see, yes currently I am taking the total likes from my backend, and the user currently can only set like or dislike in 1 post so it can't fake likes. I was just wondering if I can use UpdateExpression parameter like 'set popularity = 0 if like < 10 else 1' so I don't need to get post likes for each updated